# pegar evento click dentro do html dentro de uma varivel javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como eu pego o evento do click de codigo html dentro de uma constante criada no javascript, por exemplo como no codigo abaixo:

```
function mostrarDados(){
    resultado.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < usersDB.length; i++) {
        const e = usersDB[i];
        const usuario = `
            <div class='tabela row'>
                <div class='col'>${e.nome}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.email}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.endereco}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.bairro}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.cidade}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.telefone}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.data}</div>
                <div class='col'><a class='btn-editar' href='#'><i class='bx bxs-edit'></i></a></div>
                <div class='col'><a class='btn-deletar' href='#'><i class='bx bxs-trash'></i></a></div>
            </div>
        `;
        resultado.innerHTML += usuario;
    }

}
```

O que estou tentando fazer criar uma function editar o conteudo do localstorage, mas não estou pegando parametro na function, isso é possivel fazer?

---

Deixa eu melhor a pergunta, por exemplo:

ao criar a const usuario dentro dela tem a tag 'a' coma class btn-editar, ao criar o addEventlistener pegando a class btn-editar quando clico no btn editar no navegador não funciona.

Vou colocar todo o codigo se minha duvida fica mais clara.

```
const btnCadastrar = document.querySelector('#btn-cadastrar');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const formulario = document.querySelector('.formulario');
const salvar = document.querySelector('.salvar');
const cancelar = document.querySelector('.cancelar');
const fechar = document.querySelector('.btn-fechar');
const resultado = document.querySelector('.resultado');
const btnEditar = document.querySelector('.btn-editar');

const nome = document.querySelector('#nome');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const endereco = document.querySelector('#endereco');
const bairro = document.querySelector('#bairro');
const cidade = document.querySelector('#cidade');
const telefone = document.querySelector('#telefone');
const data = document.querySelector('#data');

const usersDB = localStorage.getItem('Usuarios') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Usuarios')) : [];

btnCadastrar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.add('show');
    modal.classList.remove('hide');
    formulario.classList.add('show-form');
    formulario.classList.remove('hide-form');
});

fechar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.add('hide');
    modal.classList.remove('show');
    formulario.classList.add('hide-form');
    formulario.classList.remove('show-form');
    formulario.reset();
});

cancelar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.add('hide');
    modal.classList.remove('show');
    formulario.classList.add('hide-form');
    formulario.classList.remove('show-form');
    formulario.reset();
});

salvar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    gravarDB();
});

function editar(){
    alert('Teste');
}

// btnEditar.addEventListener('click', function(){
//     alert('eric');
// });



function gravarDB(){
    const newId = usersDB.length +1;
    const pegaItems = {
        id: newId,
        nome: nome.value,
        email: email.value,
        endereco: endereco.value,
        bairro: bairro.value,
        cidade: cidade.value,
        telefone: telefone.value,
        data: data.value
    }
    usersDB.push(pegaItems);
    localStorage.setItem('Usuarios', JSON.stringify(usersDB));
    
    mostrarDados();
    formulario.reset();
}

function mostrarDados(){
    resultado.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < usersDB.length; i++) {
        const e = usersDB[i];
        const usuario = `
            <div class='tabela row'>
                <div class='col'>${e.nome}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.email}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.endereco}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.bairro}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.cidade}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.telefone}</div>
                <div class='col'>${e.data}</div>
                <div class='col'><a class='btn-editar' href='#'><i class='bx bxs-edit'></i></a></div>
                <div class='col'><a class='btn-deletar' href='#'><i class='bx bxs-trash'></i></a></div>
            </div>
        `;
        resultado.innerHTML += usuario;
    }

}

mostrarDados();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>CRUD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="content">
            <div class="form-cadastro">
                <div class="btn-cadastrar">
                    <a id="btn-cadastrar" href="#">Cadastrar</a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal hide">
                    <form class="formulario hide-form">
                        <header>
                            <div class="titulo">
                                <h1>Cadastro de Clientes</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-fechar">
                                <a id="btn-fechar" href="#"><i class='bx bx-log-out-circle'></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <div class="form-campos">
                            <div class="campos">
                                <div class="nome">
                                    <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo">
                                </div>
                                <div class="email">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="endereco">
                                    <input id="endereco" type="text" placeholder="Endereço">
                                </div>
                                <div class="bairro">
                                    <input id="bairro" type="text" placeholder="Bairro">
                                </div>
                                <div class="cidade">
                                    <input id="cidade" type="text" placeholder="Cidade">
                                </div>
                                <div class="telefone">
                                    <input id="telefone" type="text" placeholder="Telefone">
                                </div>
                                <div class="data">
                                    <label for="data">Data</label>
                                    <input id="data" type="date" id="data">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-salvar-cancelar">
                                <div class="salvar">
                                    <a id="btn-salvar" href="#">Salvar</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cancelar">
                                    <a id="btn-cancelar" href="#">Cancelar</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="resultado table"></div>
        </section>
    </main>


    <script src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. A julgar pelo código, você gostaria de saber como adicionar eventos a código HTML gerado dinamicamente?

Comment: Depois que os elementos criados dinamicamente existirem no DOM – ou seja, depois do seu loop `for` – é possível atrelar event listeners a eles normalmente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja ativar a função "editar()" quando o botão de edição for clicado e enviar o evento para saber qual foi o índice do botão de edição clicado.
Uma abordagem seria utilizar o evento onClick para enviar o evento. Segue um exemplo:

```
function mostrarDados(){
resultado.innerHTML = '';
for (let i = 0; i < usersDB.length; i++) {
    const e = usersDB[i];
    const usuario = `
        <div class='tabela row'>
            <div class='col'>${e.nome}</div>
            <div class='col'>${e.email}</div>
            <div class='col'>${e.endereco}</div>
            <div class='col'>${e.bairro}</div>
            <div class='col'>${e.cidade}</div>
            <div class='col'>${e.telefone}</div>
            <div class='col'>${e.data}</div>
            <div class='col'><a id=${i} class='btn-editar' href='#' onClick="editar(event)"><i class='bx bxs-edit'></i></a></div>
            <div class='col'><a id=${i} class='btn-deletar' href='#' onClick="deletar(event)"><i class='bx bxs-trash'></i></a></div>
        </div>
    `;
    resultado.innerHTML += usuario;
}
```

}

Agora lá na função que vai ser chamada:

```
function editar(e){
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log(e.id);
}
```

Dê uma olhada no `console.log(e.target);`, ele possui uma série de atributos que você pode utilizar. Por exemplo, é possível obter o texto que está dentro do botão, a posição do mouse e muito mais. Depois, confira a documentação sobre eventos do JavaScript em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event para mais informações.